# Changing language of TabControl in Window Forms at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new to Windows Forms and I am trying to make my application localizable in English and German and I want to change the language at runtime. So far, I have been able to do so by using .resx files and the following code:

```
    //fired when clicking the german MenuItem
    private void deutschToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("de-DE");
    }

    //fired when clicking the english MenuItem
    private void englischToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("en-US");
    }

    private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);
        ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Main0));
        resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
        ApplyResources(resources, this.Controls);
    }

    private void ApplyResources(ComponentResourceManager resources, Control.ControlCollection ctls)
    {
        //all controls
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
        {
            resources.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
            ApplyResources(resources, ctl.Controls);
        }

        //the menu bar and its items
        foreach (ToolStripItem item in mst_Main.Items)
        {
            if (item is ToolStripDropDownItem)
            {
                resources.ApplyResources(item, item.Name);
                foreach (ToolStripItem dropDownItem in ((ToolStripDropDownItem)item).DropDownItems)
                {
                    resources.ApplyResources(dropDownItem, dropDownItem.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works for the main form, its menubar and its controls (e.g. buttons, labels).

However, it does not work for the TabControl which is added later to the form:

```
            pan_Main.Controls.Clear();
            mainTabControl = new MainTabControl(index);
            mainTabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pan_Main.Controls.Add(mainTabControl);
            pan_Main.Controls.Add(tbl_Main);
```

If I now try to change the language (via the menu bar/MenuStrip on the main form) the language of the TabControl and all its underlying controls does not change. If I change the language, before adding the TabControl to the form (before calling its InitializeComponent()-method) the TabControl gets initialized with the correct language.

So the methods for changing the language (described above) do seem to affect the TabControl, but without updating its elements.

Is there an easy way to switch the language at runtime also for the TabControl and its underlying elements without recreating it? If so, can you tell me where my code is wrong or what I am missing. After several hours of experimenting around with the code I still could not find a solution to this problem...

Thx in advance

Comment: Your posted code is fine. The problem is somewhere else

Comment: "Added later" is no doubt the key problem.  You have to re-run ApplyResources().  With significant odds that this doesn't do much either since that tab control doesn't look like it ever met the designer.  You'd at least need a UserControl.  Using Controls.Clear() like that is a very serious bug btw, it doesn't dispose controls as is required here.  Do keep in mind that this is the kind of code that users *never* actually use, they don't actually learn a different language while they are using your form.